# How to get picture extension when it's from my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have to make a website where people can sign up and log in and then they are able to lend their car or borrow one from another user.

I made a function to upload pictures to the database and another one to show pictures from the database but it only work for the jpeg extension.

I would like to avoid making a lot of conditions to make it work for any extension( more like ~5 but all these conditions do not make the code really clean...).

My question is :
Is it possible to retrieve the extension of a picture from a database?

I'm already using
`'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($ticket['image']).'" />';` to retrieve jpeg pictures.
My idea is to replace "jpg" by a string variable and replace this variable by the name of the extension I would like to use.
I think I should  use pathinfo(X,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) but I dont know what to put in "X"

Thank you

### EDIT

I just figured out that I can change the extension in "data:image/jpg" to gif, png, etc. as I wish and it actually works.

Comment: Do you have the name of the file, including the extension?

Comment: Store the image data, file name, and extension with the file record. If you do it correctly, it won't take much effort to display it.

Comment: I can get it when I upload the picture to the database, but my goal is to get it just from variable were the picture is stored

Comment: So I absolutely must put those informations in my database ? no solution from the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your database and CRUD layer to store the file extension, then just dynamically input it into your base 64 encoding.